# Parallel kernel status is idle though program is running

Tags: kernel

[image]

The Mathematica window says that the program is running. However, the parallel kernel status says that the kernel is idle. What does this mean?

Comment: It says "idle", not "ideal", and that means it is doing nothing.

Comment: I am sorry for the silly typo. I just wanted to know why does the top of the window say "Running" when the program is doing nothing.

Comment: If you start the evaluation and then open the "Parallel Kernel Status" window, it might not update until the evaluation is finished. I have a similar problem with this. I think it may be a bug. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148190/42688