# Updating "Parallel Kernel Status" window during evaluation

Tags: front-end, parallelization

I really like the "Parallel Kernel Status" window for monitoring my parallel kernels. However, as long as a cell is evaluating, it is almost not updated (only the red and green circles that show whether a kernel is being used change). For example, if I launch some more kernels with F7, they are not shown until the currently running cell finishes its evaluation. They are being used however. Or if I kill a kernel, it is still shown in the list.

Is there a way to update this window during a running evaluation in *Mathematica 11*?